# Typescript Class Constraint String

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I try to create a class with a string contraint but the it gives an error at the get scale() function.

```
class Scaling<T extends string> {
  _scale = "";

  constructor(props: T) {
    this._scale = props;
  }

  setScale(scale: T) {
    this._scale = scale;
  }

  get scale(): T {
    return this._scale;
  }
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'string' is assignable
> to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a
> different subtype of constraint 'string'.
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_scale` member should really be of type `T`. For example:

```
class Scaling<T extends string> {
  _scale = "" as T;

  constructor(props: T) {
    this._scale = props;
  }

  setScale(scale: T) {
    this._scale = scale;
  }

  get scale(): T {
    return this._scale;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case you will not be able to call `setScale`

Comment: can you provide an example where it wouldn't work?

Comment: `const result = new Scaling("hello"); result.setScale("other") // <--- error`

Comment: that's interesting. it seems that a string literal is not really a `string`. I've tried some variations, which work: `let initial = "hello";

const result = new Scaling(initial);

result.setScale("other")` or `const result = new Scaling("hello" as string);

result.setScale("other")
` But If in the first case I say `const initial = "hello"` I would get the same error. Looking at the type of `let initial` vs `const initial` gives me different result, the fomer is a `string`, while the latter is `"hello"`, although at runtime `typeof` returns `string` in both cases, which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove explicit `T` return type from `get scale(): T`.

Because during initialization, `T` inferes as literal type of argument.
COnsider this example:

```js
class Scaling<T extends string> {
    _scale = "";

    constructor(props: T) {
        this._scale = props;
    }

    setScale(scale: T) {
        this._scale = scale;
    }

    get scale(): T {
        return this._scale;
    }
}

// T infered as literal "hello"
const result = new Scaling('hello')
```

Hence, when you want to return `T` it should be `"hello"`.

In your example, it can't be `"hello"` because default value of `_scale` is empty string and accordingly it is infered as a string.

```js
let str = ''

// Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"hello"'
const sameCase = (): 'hello' => str
```

You can't use `T` as an explicit type for `_scale` because `_scale` is mutable and types are immutable.

This is why it is unsafe to return `T` type from `get scale`

> Even if i remove the T from the get scale, i still get an error when for const result = new Scaling("hello"); result.setScale("other")

My bad, did not check it.

In order to make this class generic we need to convert infered `T` from more specific type to more wider.

```js
type Infer<T> = T extends infer R ? R : never

class Scaling<T extends string> {
  _scale = "";

  constructor(props: Infer<T>) {
    this._scale = props;
  }

  setScale(scale: T) {
    this._scale = scale;
  }

  get scale() {
    return this._scale;
  }
}

// T infered as literal "hello"
const result = new Scaling('hello') // ok

result.setScale('123') // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgMwgJwDwBUB8UC8V1QQAewEcAJgM5QCWiKUASlAPxNQBcUcEAbigCgBAYwA2AQ0rUAysPGi6AcwyESZKlErBkS7AG8BUKAH1Kc0dDwAiKwG4hR4QHs4W5AFdhwJ8gAUYZCcwSi54JDQsAEooAyMjYAALGkoAOlNzSygAoMp7IwBfB00IYFl5CF8zcq50aNi4xOS0qotcTQy8qELDKEUS9vLfOp6jZBL3ZDgoRtT08s7C7oB6JfxaejHyKEkoBVJkeSgrBIhRUScrERctKDHKd1FgNp4AdygyhThFXwByE7OnD9IkI7g9gClKCUPhUfgBGABMAGYgUA)

Comment: Even if i remove the T from the get scale, i still get an error when for const result = new Scaling("hello"); result.setScale("other");

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't _scale be of type `T`? So you'd assign with a colon (:)

```
class Scaling<T extends string> {
  _scale: T;

  constructor(props: T) {
    this._scale = props;
  }

  setScale(scale: T) {
    this._scale = scale;
  }

  get scale(): T {
    return this._scale;
  }
}
```

The usage would be:

```
const scaling = new Scaling('Hello World')
console.log(scaling)
```